# Hamburger Drop Down Not Responding To Click Event

Tags: javascript, html

In my title , I wrote hamburger dd but none of my component seem to be responding to me clicking on them.
Have no idea why is this happening and would love if anyone here could help me.
(In short , nothing happens when I click on the hamburger menu).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <title>MY CSS WEBSITE</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
         <nav>
            <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
            
              <li>
                  <a href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#news">News</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="topnav-right">
                  <a href="#signUp">Sign Up</a>
              </li>
              <li class="topnav-right">
                  <a href="#signIn">Sign In</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdownIcon">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="dropdownMenu">☰</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>     
    <script> 
        function dropdownMenu(){
            console.log(hello);
            var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
            if(ddc.className === "topnav"){
                x.className += " responsive";
            }
            /*change topnav to topnav.responsive*/
            else{
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few issues in your js.
First of all, you need to make sure you are keeping variable names consistent. (You were using `ddc` instead of `x` in places. Furthermore, make sure that strings are inside of quotes, otherwise, they are treated as variables.

Fixed code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <title>MY CSS WEBSITE</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
         <nav>
            <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
            
              <li>
                  <a href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#news">News</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="topnav-right">
                  <a href="#signUp">Sign Up</a>
              </li>
              <li class="topnav-right">
                  <a href="#signIn">Sign In</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdownIcon">
                  <a href="javascript:dropdownMenu()">☰</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>     
    <script> 
        function dropdownMenu(){
            console.log("hello");
            var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
            if(x.className === "topnav"){
                x.className += " responsive";
            }
            /*change topnav to topnav.responsive*/
            else{
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```